# Multiple Count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and i am trying to get count from both tables. Means count from first table then count from 2nd table and result should look like this.

```
Count(users.name)   Count(users_types)
        5                    8
```

But my query brings this result

```
Count(users.name)   Count(users_types)
        8                    8
```

Here is my query

```
select count(users.users),
count(users_types.users_types)
form users , users_types
```

How can i get correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub query like this

```
select
  count(users.users)    Users,
  (select
     count(users_types.users_types)
   from teams)    UsersTypes
from users
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select
(select count(users.users) from users),
(select count(users_types.users_types) form users_types)
```

Comment: This works fine, but slows down the query significantly when the tables contains large amount of data. The original question seems to want it done without the speed issue.

Comment: well, nothing as such is mentioned in the question..!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer, but why not add the alternative answer that allows for faster results.

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select count(*) cnt1 from table1),
 (select count(*) cnt2 from table2)
```